# NullReferenceException with XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

When this line of code is run, I receive a System.NullReferenceException.

```
// Occurs on this line
if (xDoc.Root.Element("data").Element("forecast").Element("record").Value == "0")
{
    tempnow.Text = xDoc.Root.Element("data").Element("forecast").Element("pop").Value;
}
```

Xdoc is defined below the class, if this is related to it.

```
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        XDocument xDoc;
```

This is the XML document  I am attempting to access and find the value of "record". This is also the document "Xdoc" represents, with information about that below.

```
<data>
  <status>success</status>
  <location>
    <city/>
    <fullName>39.6N, 0.3W - 6miles SW of El Puerto, SP</fullName>
    <localDate>2014-01-30T01:29:23</localDate>
    <localEpoch>1391045363</localEpoch>
    <locationID>GP202368</locationID>
  </location>
  <forecast>
    <record>0</record>
    <utcEpoch>1391040000</utcEpoch>
    <utcDate>2014-01-30T00:00:00</utcDate>
    <maxTempC>15.4</maxTempC>
    <maxTempF>59.7</maxTempF>
    <minTempC>5.2</minTempC>
    <minTempF>41.3</minTempF>
    <fcstDay>1</fcstDay>
    <dayLength>10:07</dayLength>
    <sunriseHHMMLocal>8:11am</sunriseHHMMLocal>
    <sunsetHHMMLocal>6:18pm</sunsetHHMMLocal>
    <nightLength/>
    <moonriseHHMMLocal/>
    <moonsetHHMMLocal/>
    <moonphase/>
    <moonillum/>
    <moonicon/>
    <pop>19</pop>
    <uv_index>2</uv_index>
    <gustC>30</gustC>
    <gustF>19</gustF>
    <heatindexC>-999.99</heatindexC>
    <heatindexF>-999.99</heatindexF>
    <icon>partly-cloudy-sm.png</icon>
    <iconBase>partly-cloudy</iconBase>
    <iconLg>partly-cloudy.png</iconLg>
    <prcpC>0</prcpC>
    <prcpF>0</prcpF>
    <rh>33</rh>
    <skyCover>8</skyCover>
    <snowC>0</snowC>
    <snowF>0</snowF>
    <wdir>NW</wdir>
    <windchillC>-999.99</windchillC>
    <windchillF>-999.99</windchillF>
    <wspdC>16</wspdC>
    <wspdF>10</wspdF>
    <wx>Mostly Sunny</wx>
  </forecast>
  <forecast>
    <record>1</record>
    <utcEpoch>1391126400</utcEpoch>
    <utcDate>2014-01-31T00:00:00</utcDate>
    <maxTempC>16</maxTempC>
    <maxTempF>60.8</maxTempF>
    <minTempC>5</minTempC>
    <minTempF>40.9</minTempF>
    <fcstDay>2</fcstDay>
    <dayLength>10:09</dayLength>
    <sunriseHHMMLocal>8:10am</sunriseHHMMLocal>
    <sunsetHHMMLocal>6:19pm</sunsetHHMMLocal>
    <nightLength/>
    <moonriseHHMMLocal/>
    <moonsetHHMMLocal/>
    <moonphase/>
    <moonillum/>
    <moonicon/>
    <pop>18</pop>
    <uv_index>2</uv_index>
    <gustC>30</gustC>
    <gustF>19</gustF>
    <heatindexC>-999.99</heatindexC>
    <heatindexF>-999.99</heatindexF>
    <icon>partly-cloudy-sm.png</icon>
    <iconBase>partly-cloudy</iconBase>
    <iconLg>partly-cloudy.png</iconLg>
    <prcpC>0</prcpC>
    <prcpF>0</prcpF>
    <rh>46</rh>
    <skyCover>28</skyCover>
    <snowC>0</snowC>
    <snowF>0</snowF>
    <wdir>WNW</wdir>
    <windchillC>-999.99</windchillC>
    <windchillF>-999.99</windchillF>
    <wspdC>13</wspdC>
    <wspdF>8</wspdF>
    <wx>Mostly Sunny</wx>
  </forecast>
  <forecast>
    <record>2</record>
    <utcEpoch>1391212800</utcEpoch>
    <utcDate>2014-02-01T00:00:00</utcDate>
    <maxTempC>18.1</maxTempC>
    <maxTempF>64.5</maxTempF>
    <minTempC>6.4</minTempC>
    <minTempF>43.5</minTempF>
    <fcstDay>3</fcstDay>
    <dayLength>10:12</dayLength>
    <sunriseHHMMLocal>8:09am</sunriseHHMMLocal>
    <sunsetHHMMLocal>6:21pm</sunsetHHMMLocal>
    <nightLength/>
    <moonriseHHMMLocal/>
    <moonsetHHMMLocal/>
    <moonphase/>
    <moonillum/>
    <moonicon/>
    <pop>46</pop>
    <uv_index>2</uv_index>
    <gustC>49</gustC>
    <gustF>31</gustF>
    <heatindexC>-999.99</heatindexC>
    <heatindexF>-999.99</heatindexF>
    <icon>light-rain-shower-sm.png</icon>
    <iconBase>light-rain-shower</iconBase>
    <iconLg>light-rain-shower.png</iconLg>
    <prcpC>0.2</prcpC>
    <prcpF>0.09</prcpF>
    <rh>35</rh>
    <skyCover>27</skyCover>
    <snowC>0</snowC>
    <snowF>0</snowF>
    <wdir>WNW</wdir>
    <windchillC>-999.99</windchillC>
    <windchillF>-999.99</windchillF>
    <wspdC>22</wspdC>
    <wspdF>14</wspdF>
    <wx>Light Rain Showers</wx>
  </forecast>
  <forecast>
    <record>3</record>
    <utcEpoch>1391299200</utcEpoch>
    <utcDate>2014-02-02T00:00:00</utcDate>
    <maxTempC>15.9</maxTempC>
    <maxTempF>60.7</maxTempF>
    <minTempC>4.2</minTempC>
    <minTempF>39.6</minTempF>
    <fcstDay>4</fcstDay>
    <dayLength>10:14</dayLength>
    <sunriseHHMMLocal>8:08am</sunriseHHMMLocal>
    <sunsetHHMMLocal>6:22pm</sunsetHHMMLocal>
    <nightLength/>
    <moonriseHHMMLocal/>
    <moonsetHHMMLocal/>
    <moonphase/>
    <moonillum/>
    <moonicon/>
    <pop>12</pop>
    <uv_index>2</uv_index>
    <gustC>41</gustC>
    <gustF>26</gustF>
    <heatindexC>-999.99</heatindexC>
    <heatindexF>-999.99</heatindexF>
    <icon>sunny-sm.png</icon>
    <iconBase>sunny</iconBase>
    <iconLg>sunny.png</iconLg>
    <prcpC>0</prcpC>
    <prcpF>0</prcpF>
    <rh>34</rh>
    <skyCover>0</skyCover>
    <snowC>0</snowC>
    <snowF>0</snowF>
    <wdir>WNW</wdir>
    <windchillC>-999.99</windchillC>
    <windchillF>-999.99</windchillF>
    <wspdC>19</wspdC>
    <wspdF>12</wspdF>
    <wx>Sunny</wx>
  </forecast>
</data>
```

How I define that Xdoc represents the document above, downloaded from the internet:

```
//Make Webclient Request
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.wt360.com/data/forecast/daily-4day?key=ic1uji3s9zjnjgcd6hq64ny6alkoin9119vjrxc1wwngdzuihk&l=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&fmt=xml"));
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, n) =>
// ^ This is in a different method then the code receiving the NullReferenceException.
xDoc = XDocument.Parse(n.Result);
```

Answer (score 5):

`xDoc.Root` is already `<data>` element, so you don't have to call `.Element("data")` again.

Following should work just fine:

```
tempnow.Text = xDoc.Root.Element("forecast").Element("pop").Value;
```

however, I'd rather use `(string)XElement` casting:

```
tempnow.Text = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("forecast").Element("pop");
```

Comment: For some reason, still getting the same error. Here's the code, modified with your awnser:                                                                                                                                `if (xDoc.Root.Element("forecast").Element("pop").Value == "0"){
                    tempnow.Text = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("forecast").Element("pop");
                }`